# I'm trying to change event procedure s for multiple workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, event-handling, runtime-error

Please help as I stuck in error saying
"object variable or with block variable not set.
Error #91
It stucked in wb.close line
Please help as need to change the event procedure for multiple workbooks
Any idea

```
    Sub CopyCode()

  Dim wb As Workbook

  Dim strInput
  Dim VBP As Object, VBC As Object, CM As Object
  Dim strpath As String, strCurrentFile As String
  
 
  strpath = "C:\Users\Basem Lap\Desktop\test\"
  strCurrentFile = Dir(strpath & "*.xls"*)
   
  

  
  
  
  Do While strCurrentFile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strpath & strCurrentFile)
    Set VBP = wb.VBProject
    Set VBC = VBP.VBComponents(wb.CodeName)
    Set CM = VBC.CodeModule
    
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    With wb.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule
     .ReplaceLine 1, "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)" 
       
    End With
    
    
    
    
    wb.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set wb = Nothing
    strCurrentFile = Dir
  Loop
  
  MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you have written in the first lines of the relevant modules (`ThisWorkbook`)? If you don't have a procedure that in the lines below ends with `End Sub`, then even `DisplayAlerts` can't help you, because this will end in a `Compile Error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, change:

```
strCurrentFile = Dir(strpath & "*.xls"*)
```

with:

```
strCurrentFile = Dir(strpath & "*.xls*")
```

Wild character must be inside the string.

But I cannot understand how your code could pass over this. The error should (firstly) be raised on the above mentioned line...

Please, try adding this code line immediately after the line in discussion:

```
Debug.Print strCurrentFile: Stop
```

What does it return when the code stops? Is it a real workbook full name?

I would recommend that, when trying to modify something in a code module, to add a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility xx" library and appropriately declare the used variables. You will benefit of the intellisense suggestions, which may help a lot.

**Edited:**

If the code line to be replaced is the first one, your existing code should replace it with what you want. If it is not, please use the next code which will firstly search for the code to be replaces string, and make the replacement there where it is:

```
Function ReplaceCodeLine(wb As Workbook, strModule As String, strSearch As String, strReplace As String) As Boolean
 Dim VBProj As Object, VBComp As Object, CodeMod As Object
 Dim startL As Long, endL As Long
 Dim strCLine As String, boolFound As Boolean

    Set VBProj = wb.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(strModule)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    startL = 1
    With CodeMod
        endL = .CountOfLines
        boolFound = .Find(Target:=strSearch, StartLine:=startL, StartColumn:=1, _
              EndLine:=endL, EndColumn:=255, wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, _
                                                             patternsearch:=False)

        If boolFound Then
            strCLine = Replace(CodeMod.Lines(startL, 1), strSearch, _
                                     strReplace, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            .ReplaceLine startL, strCLine
            ReplaceCodeLine = True
        Else
            ReplaceCodeLine = False
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

It can be called from your code by copying the above function in a standard module and replacing the next part:

```
With wb.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule
     .ReplaceLine 1, "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)" 
       
End With
```

with this one:

```
Dim strExist as String, strToReplace as String
strExist = "Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)"
strToReplace = "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)"
Debug.Print ReplaceCodeLine(wb, "ThisWorkbook", strExist, strToReplace)
```

It will return in `Immediate Window` `True` if the line to be replaced has been found and the replacement took place.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

**Edited second time**:

The following solution will use a workbook having a **correct** "ThisWorkbook" code module, which will be copied to all the workbooks in the `strPath`folder. You must take care of the `strCurrentFile` value. It may allow .xlsx documents, which cannot be saved with VBA inside...

1. The following solution needs a reference to 'Microsoft Visual for Applications Extensibility 5.3'. In order to add it programmatically, please copy the next code in a standard module and run it:

```
Sub addExtenssibilityReference()
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
        GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
        Major:=5, Minor:=3
End Sub
```

2. Your existing code should be replaced by the next one:

```
Sub CopyThisWorkbookCode()
'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Visual for Applications Extensibility 5.3'.
 Dim VBProjSource As VBIDE.VBProject, VBCompSource As VBIDE.VBComponent
 Dim VBProjTarget As VBIDE.VBProject, wb As Workbook, strCode As String
 
 Set VBProjSource = ThisWorkbook.VBProject 'or another (open) workbook keeping
                                           'the ThisWorkbook code to be copyed from
 Set VBCompSource = VBProjSource.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
 'all ThisWorkbook module code copied as string:
 strCode = VBCompSource.CodeModule.Lines(1, VBCompSource.CodeModule.CountOfLines)

  Dim strPath As String, strCurrentFile As String
  
  strPath = "C:\Users\Basem Lap\Desktop\test\"
  strCurrentFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    
  Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
  Do While strCurrentFile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strCurrentFile)
    Set VBProjTarget = wb.VBProject
        
    impThisWorkbookModule VBProjTarget, strCode
    
    wb.Close savechanges:=True
    strCurrentFile = Dir
  Loop
  
  Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  
  MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Please, take care of `VBProjSource` choosing. In the above code, I used the workbook keeping this code. You may use another one: `Set VBProjSource = Workbooks("Model Workbook").VBProject`.

3. Copy the next function below the above code:

```
Function impThisWorkbookModule(VBProjT As VBIDE.VBProject, strCode As String)
  Dim VBCompTarget As VBIDE.VBComponent
        
  Set VBCompTarget = VBProjT.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
     
    With VBCompTarget.CodeModule
        .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
        .InsertLines 1, strCode
    End With
End Function
```

4. Run `CopyThisWorkbookCode` `Sub` and send some feedback.

Comment: OP is using late bound. No reference to library needed.

Comment: @VBasic2008: English is not my best point, unfortunately... I adapted the code to reflect what I meant.

Comment: @Basem Zaki: Did you follow my suggestion? I mean the `Debug.Print` suggestion... What does it return when code stops on `Stop`? In Immediate Window (being in VBE: `Ctrl + G`).

Comment: @faneduru no thing happened it shows the same error

Comment: @Basem Zaki: Please, read carefully my question. Using `Debug.Print` does not solve the problem. It may give you good information about the error reason. So, firstly, did you use it as I suggested? Then, does the code stop on it? If yes, what does it return in Immediate Window? Is it a real name of a workbook?

Comment: Sir, i put this line after wb.close savechanges:=ture.         But the error is raising

Comment: Puting Debug.Print.  Before the line  is stopping the run. Putting it after the line the same error is raising

Comment: @Basem Zaki: It looks we speak different languages. I do not speak about English... I never suggested placing of a `Debug.Print` code line after or before the problematic line. I never suggested that this line will solve the error. Putting it where I suggested, could conclude that the iteration between the workbooks to be processed works as expected or not. If it works, the problem must be searched in the second part of the code. If you only replace/remove the "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)" the event code will still remain, but missing only the above line returning error

Comment: @Basem Zaki: When the code stops on error, I would suggest to end the code and go in `ThisWorkbook` code module and see what remained from the event in discussion. The code, as you try to use it, does not remove the event. It removes only its first code line...

Comment: Sir, i really appreciate your decent way in speaking and discussing. Thanks a lot . Please any idea of how to change ( ByVal Sh As Object , ByVal Target As Range).  Into.   Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean).   Without any errors. thank you again

Comment: @Basem Zaki: I know how to replace a code line with another one, but if your existing event has some code involving the parameter objects (`Sh`, `Target`), only the replacement will not solve your problem. I can edit my answer and place such a function, but I am not so sure that you understand how such events work... Can you edit your question and post your existing event like it is (`Workbook_SheetChange`, I suppose)? I will tell you after that if the replacement will work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223616/discussion-between-basem-zaki-and-faneduru).

Comment: It says  "User-defined type not defined" and the first line is highlighted in yellow, i copied your code then mine and replace the part that you mentioned

Comment: @Basem Zaki: I am using early binding, in order to take advantage of intellisense suggestion and I forgot to comment the function first line. Please, comment it and try again. I adapted the code in this way...

Comment: OMG. It wooorks. It works well man . You are greaat you are really great . Greetings for you and for this amazing website  Thank you very much again and again and again .. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help! But we here when somebody spends some time in order to answer our question, vote the answer up and more important, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Answer (score 0):

### Change Type of Event Procedure

- Something like this could be a solution. Hopefully the event procedures start in the first line.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCode()

    Const ReplaceString As String = _
      "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim VBP As Object, VBC As Object, CM As Object
    Dim strpath As String, strCurrentFile As String
   
    strpath = "C:\Users\Basem Lap\Desktop\test\"
    strCurrentFile = Dir(strpath & "*.xls*")
    
    Do While strCurrentFile <> ""
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strpath & strCurrentFile)
        ' Debug.Print wb.FullName
        Set VBP = wb.VBProject
        Set VBC = VBP.VBComponents(wb.CodeName)
        Set CM = VBC.CodeModule
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        CM.ReplaceLine 1, ReplaceString
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        strCurrentFile = Dir
    
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: @BasemZaki: Try to uncomment the line `Debug.Print wb.FullName` to see the exact file, maybe more importantly its extension, where the error is occurring. The code is working fine on my side, if there is an event procedure starting in the first line of each `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: I did that, uncommented the line  abd it shows that same error.  While debug and move the mouse on the uncommented line it shows that wb = the file name.   I can't determine why it is stuck closing the file. I can change any line but the 1st one to BeforClose event the code is working to change to other events but not BeforeClose

Comment: Is it something related to the code that below the event that is already written in the module?    I think it is implementing, so the code couldn't close the file.   Any idea to put the event without implementing the below lines?

Comment: Events have different arguments (the stuff in parentheses e.g. `Cancel`). The event you are trying to change may have other arguments. Why don't you reveal what event you are trying to change?

Comment: The event that already exist is "Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange ( ByVal Sh As Object , ByVal Target As Range).